# How to remove duplicates from a string except it's first occurence

Tags: string

I've been given the following exercise but can't seem to get it working.

```
//Remove duplicate characters in a
// given string keeping only the first occurrences. 
// For example, if the input is ‘tree traversal’ 
// the output will be "tre avsl".
// ---------------------
var params = 'tree traversal word';

var removeDuplicates = function (string) {
  return string;
};

// This function runs the application
// ---------------------
var run = function() {
  // We execute the function returned here, 
  // passing params as arguments
  return removeDuplicates;
};
```

What I've done -

```
var removeDuplicates = function (string) {

  var word ='';
    for(var i=0; i < string.length; i++){
      if(string[i] == " "){  
            word += string[i] + " ";
      }
      else if(string.lastIndexOf(string[i]) == string.indexOf(string[i]))
      {
        word += string[i];
      }
    }

  return word;
};
```

I'm not allowed to use replaceAll and when I create an inner for loop it doesn't work.

Comment: show the inner loop code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    function removeDuplicates(string)
    {
        var result = [];

        var i = null;
        var length = string.length;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1)
        {
            var current = string.charAt(i);

            if (result.indexOf(current) === -1)
            {
                result.push(current);
            }

        }

        return result.join("");
    }

    function removeDuplicatesRegex(string)
    {
        return string.replace(/(.)(?=\1)/g, ""); 
    }
  var str = "tree traversal";
  alert(removeDuplicates(str));
</script>
```

Comment: @user1645888 Please accept this as the correct answer then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the run function should be returning `removeDuplicates(params)`, right?

You're on the right lines, but need to think about this condition again:

`else if(string.lastIndexOf(string[i]) == string.indexOf(string[i]))`

With `i = 0` and taking `'tree traversal word'` as the example, `lastIndexOf()` is going to be returning 5 (the index of the 2nd 't'), whereas indexOf() will be returning 0.

Obviously this isn't what you want, because 't' hasn't yet been appended to `word` yet (but it  is a repeated character, which is what your condition does actually test for).

Because you're gradually building up `word`, think about testing to see if the character `string[i]` exists in `word` already  for each iteration of your for loop. If it doesn't, append it.

(maybe this will come in handy: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)

Good luck!